# Codeblocks takes long time to execute after compiling

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks

I am having a strange problem with Code:Blocks. After writing C program i click on Build and run, it compiles in fraction of a second but then a new window opens and after around 12 seconds output appears on the window.
It takes this much time for even basic code like

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("HELLO");
    return 0;
}
```

Here are snapshots of what happens. As I am not allowed to post images{new to forum} I am posting links.

When I click on build and run, this window appears in no time

[image]

Then after around 10-12 seconds, this window appears. As you can see it says that execution time took 11 seconds.

[image]

Any idea why this is happening? How to fix it? I did no tweaks to code:blocks and settings are same as they come by default.

Comment: add a getchar() after the printf() and run it again.

Comment: It is taking that much execution time of whole code. If getchar was causing problem, printf would have still given output instantly. Though i tried getchar(); and it still took that much time.

Comment: Do you mean the problem is that it takes a long time to show the first output?

Comment: Yeah I guess my question states that. The execution time is long. Even if its a blank program, it will run only after 10 seconds.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=16557.0

Comment: @mok tried it. Doesnt solve the problem

Comment: Antivirus "live" protection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with antivirus. Whitlisting gcc,g++ and codeblocks solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. Later I found out that, its due to antivirus. I don't have any antivirus install in my PC. It was windows Virus and threats protection which was running all the time, which make execution slow.

What I did is, Go to Manage settings. After that you will found Exclusions somewhere. Go to exclusions. Then go to Add/remove exclusions. 
There just add the folder where your .c or .cpp file is created. And then you are done.

Adding a youtube link which can be useful
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OaQQsDIsc8o]

Answer (score 1):

For any Avast user reading this

1. Open the interface
2. Go to settings
3. Go to general
4. Scroll down and you will find 'exclusion'
5. Enter the directory in which your CodeBlocks is installed. Also enter the directory in which you have saved your project.

Answer (score 0):

What is the setting of  Settings -> Compiler -> your compiler -> Build options -> Number of processors?

For your CPU it should be 8-12. This option will help you if you have many files. If you have 1 file it doesn't matter.

p.s. you've not mentioned what compiler you're using, so this might be the cause.
p.p.s. gcc on windows is slower than the linux version, 2x and more times slower...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot, if your Processor is at 1-2Ghz frequency then , the no. of processors should be 4-5 else if it is a high end pc with more than 8gb RAM and greater than 2.5Ghz frequency the..anything between 8-12 you may try what works best....

Comment: why won't you edit your question with this complement you posted here in comments?

Answer (score 0):

Even without antivirus, Windows Defender(in Windows 11) was slowing it down for me.

When I excluded the folder, it started to work faster for me.

Steps for excluding the folder from Windows Defender scan in Windows 11 (10 might be same I guess):

1. Open up Windows Security app.
2. go to Virus and threat protection.
3. Under Virus and threat protection settings, click Manage settings.
4. Scroll to last, under Exclusion click on Add or remove exclusions.
5. Click yes for the permission.
6. there you can add the file/folder to exclude from.

Now build and run your code, it should run faster. If not then sorry your problem seems to bigger than this solution.